# swift 3 Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I'm trying to use a func I extended UIViewController with. I added self to the different func's arguments but the func not gives me "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit" error. Tried even to apply a weak self reference. The func seems to be never running anyway

te array is declared

```
var managedComicsArray = [NSManagedObject]()
```

in viewDidLoad :

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
    managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

the button

```
@IBAction func addComicButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    print("add button tapped")

    weak var weakSelf = self // ADD THIS LINE AS WELL


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Some default text"
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
//            let textField = alert.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
        let textField = alert!.textFields![0]
        print("Text from textField: \(textField.text)")


        guard let grabbedNumber = Int16(textField.description) else {return}
//the func below gives the error
        weakSelf?.addRecordIfnotPresent(newIssueNumber: grabbedNumber, theManagedContext: self.managedContext, theEntityName: self.kComicEntityName, managedArray: &self.managedComicsArray)


        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


   //end of button
}
```

the extended method:

```
func addRecordIfnotPresent(newIssueNumber: Int16, theManagedContext: NSManagedObjectContext, theEntityName: String, managedArray: inout [NSManagedObject]) {

    print("adding func started")

    let comicFetch: NSFetchRequest<Comic> = Comic.fetchRequest()
    var isPresent = true

    do {
        managedArray = try theManagedContext.fetch(comicFetch)


        if !managedArray.isEmpty {

        //*****************************************************************
        for comic in managedArray {

            var comicToCheck = Comic()
            comicToCheck = comic as! Comic

            if comicToCheck.wholeSeriesNumber == newIssueNumber {
                print("number \(newIssueNumber) is alredy present")
                return
            } else {
                isPresent = false
                print("number not present, keep on!")
            }

        }


        guard isPresent == false else {return}
        saveSingleComicWithNumber(withIssueNumber: Int(newIssueNumber), theEntityName: theEntityName, theManagedContext: theManagedContext)
        print("created Comic!")
        try theManagedContext.save()
        print("saved context!")
        //*****************************************************************

        } else {
            saveSingleComicWithNumber(withIssueNumber: Int(newIssueNumber), theEntityName: theEntityName, theManagedContext: theManagedContext)

        }










    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}






func saveSingleComicWithNumber(withIssueNumber: Int, theEntityName: String, theManagedContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: theEntityName, in: theManagedContext)!

    let comicToAdd = Comic(entity: entity, insertInto: theManagedContext)


    comicToAdd.wholeSeriesNumber = Int16(withIssueNumber)
    comicToAdd.issueInCollection = false
    comicToAdd.titleOfItalianSerie = "title"

    if comicToAdd.wholeSeriesNumber == 2 {
        comicToAdd.issueInCollection = false
    }


    do {
        try theManagedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there is no need for `weak self` in your method. You can capture strongly. The controller cannot be deallocated when the alert is still visible.

Comment: fine! I applied 'self.addRecordIfnotPresent' is that you mean? but something must be wrong with the grabbing/converting from the alert, the func never evalues

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem at all. Your original code compiles fine for me. If the function does not evaluate it probably means `Int16(textField.description)` fails and your `guard` returns.

Comment: @biggreentree same here i don't have any problem in compiling your code. Can you post what you doing in your `addRecordIfnotPresent` function

Comment: thanks for your help, added the function

Comment: @biggreentree  How is `self.managedComicsArray` declared? Why do you use an `inout` param instead of returning it as a normal return value?

Comment: when I moved the func in a separate swift file as an extension it was required to change it so in order the func to be working, so the func is used directly as any VC  method

Comment: sorry, read wrong your question! is declare this way     var managedComicsArray = [NSManagedObject]()

Comment: The function cannot run because your `Int16(textField.description)` line will never let it continue. You cannot use `textField.description`. You have to use `textField.text`, e.g. `Int16(textField.text ?? "")`.